# Installing SQL Sever 2008 R2 Native Client Not Working

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, sqlncli

I'm struggling to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client using MSIExec through VBScript. I'm trying to complete the installation without the user needing to interact with the installer but I'm getting the error message `The required IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES command-line parameter is missing.`

I'm trying to execute the code as below (which obviously incorporates the required parameter!) but I'm still getting the error message. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim wShell

Set wShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

wShell.Run "msiexec.exe /i C:\sqlncli.msi /qb IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES"
wShell.Run "msiexec.exe /i C:\sqlncli.msi /qb IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS="""YES""""
```

Just to clarify the exact command and outcome, see the picture below:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

From Help

> Property values that are literal strings must be enclosed in quotation marks. Include any white spaces in the string between the marks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've just tried. If I enclose `IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES` in either double quotes or single quotes, the Windows Installer window opens with the help guide and doesn't execute the package.

Comment: If I enclose `IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES` in either double quotes or single quotes, the Windows Installer window opens with the help guide and doesn't execute the package

Comment: `IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS="YES"` is the format for a string property. Is it a string property? According to the SQL docs it isn't a string property. I think `/Passive` and `/qb` are mutually exclusive. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with the exact command that I'm executing and the outcome. Still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Try `msiexec.exe /i C:\sqlncli.msi /qb IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that one aswell to no avail, I still get the error!

Comment: How big is it and what is the download link. See this web site that it seems you need to do a lot to install it silently. https://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008/ plus the MS examples always have GUIDs on the command line. Seethis as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx